# Чем отличается jsoup от Htmlcleaner?

Tags: android

Jsoup подойдет для клиент-серверного приложения для обмена текстом?

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите обмениваться данными с сервером посредством HTML? Это же так ущербно...

Comment: Без дополнительной информации сложно что-то сказать, но JSOUP для общения между клиентом и сервером - это я даже сложно себе представляю. Лучше уж по средством JSON общаться: сервер формирует JSON, клиенты его скачивают и анализирует.